# How to make italic and indentation

Tags: spacing

I use WinShell in Windows. I want to make italic text and indent it. I tried the following:

```
\textit {\quad {text here}}
```

But i get italic effect only. Can you please help me.

Comment: Can you provide the surrounding code (in the form of a minimum working example) to help give context to your usage?

Comment: It's hard to tell without a complete example, but I guess that you should try `\quad\textit{text here}`  -- it makes no sense to try to set a blank space in italics.

Comment: tex ignores blank spaces at the beginnings of lines, unless explicitly told otherwise.  you can get the space you want using `\hspace*{1em}` (the `*` is the instruction to pay attention).  but really, a minimum working example would be welcome.

Comment: @Thruston: Why not a *blank space*? This reminds me of an old comic strip, about how to pronounce a question mark… :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess is that you try to make a italic, indented quotation. Use the excellent package [quoting](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quoting):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[font=itshape]{quoting}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{quoting}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quoting}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]